# Tailwind: Manually trigger screen size change

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a component demo container where one can drag a slider to change the width to see the responsive component changing. Similar to this first component and how there is a slider to resize the container.

[Example](https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/application-shells/stacked)

Since Tailwind/normal css relies on the window size to be responsive... how can I make the size of the container force the component to adjust as if it's the actual screen size?

I don't think it's setting the window width directly since if I have multiple components on the page, they would all change which is not what I want.